cannot Disable ssl verification in next js app
My nest js backend is on my local network with self signed certificate in https.
In my next js front end i want to call my api at https://back-address/login:4000 but since it's a dev certificate self signed i get an error:
POST http://back-address:4000/auth/login net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
On postman it works when i disable ssl verification.
I tried to set env variable to NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 but it didn't change anything i still had the same error
I also tried
const instance = axios.create({
            httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            })
        });

        const response = await instance.post(URL + "/auth/login", {
            login,
            password,
        });

But it didn't change anything neither.

In short: you cannot programmatically disable certificate validation in the browser. The methods you've tried about use of https.Agent outside the browser.

is there another solution ? like add manually the certificate in the front part to bypass it?

There is no solution which does not involve each client explicitly trusting the server or - in case of corporate environments - automatically distribute the necessary certificates to the trust store of the managed corporate devices.
